# colors and brackets in nbconvert latex citations

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to modify my nbconvert template to

1. Just show the citations in the text in b/w, not green
2. Have round brackets rather than square brackets

I think the following lines should achieve this

```
((* block bibpackages *))
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
((* endblock bibpackages *))
```

but when I include this in my custom template (in full below, in case other content matters?) doesn't have any effect.

Any idea what the problem is here?

And are there any general considerations worth knowing when modifying these templates? Often seems a bit hit and miss.

Ta!

```
((*- extends 'latex_article.tplx' -*))

((* block date *))
\date{}
((* endblock date *))

((* block author *))
\author{}
((* endblock author *))

((* block title *))
\title{}
((* endblock title *))

((* block bibpackages *))
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
((* endblock bibpackages *))

((* block bibliography *))
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Thesis}
((* endblock bibliography *))

% Disable input cells 
((* block input_group *))
((* endblock input_group *))


((= This line selects the cell style. =))
((* set cell_style = 'style_bw_python.tplx' *))
```

Comment: There might be some issues you are facing: 1) which ipython version do you use - it seems like you mix some versions. 2) Even in ipython 2.0 there is no such bibpackages block in the latex template.

Comment: Ok I most likely added bibpackages myself there, thinking that was essentially just code annotation. Is there any documentation for how these blocks function?
There are quite a few latex things I would like to add in, in addition to the ones above. Would they need to go together in one block? 
Im using 2.0 ftom github. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IPython templates are jinja2 powered, so the respective [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) is a good place to start.

To get an idea of the available blocks have a look at the applied templates. For the current master you can find the IPython latex templates e.g. [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/IPython/nbconvert/templates/latex) (Btw. note that in current master there is no latex_article.tplx any more!)

If you look at the base template (the article template extends from this one) you will see that there is a *packages* block ([here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/nbconvert/templates/latex/base.tplx#L15)). So you would like to include your *usepackage* calls to this block.
To do so, you could simply create a custom template which extends the *article* template and include a *packages* block with the original calls and add yours. Alternatively, use the `super` keyword instead of copying the original ones (see [here](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/?highlight=extends#super-blocks)).

#### Update:

Based on your input a possible template taking care of the link color and the natbib package could look like the following

```
((= This line inherits from the built in template that you want to use. =))
((* extends 'article.tplx' *))

((* block date *))
\date{\today}
((* endblock date *))

((* block author *))
\author{Mr. Magoo}
((* endblock author *))

((* block title *))
\title{Fantastic memories}
((* endblock title *))

((* block packages *))
((( super() )))
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
((* endblock packages *))

((* block commands *))
    % Prevent overflowing lines due to hard-to-break entities
    \sloppy
    % Setup hyperref package
    \hypersetup{
      breaklinks=true, % so long urls are correctly broken across lines
      hidelinks
      }
    % Slightly bigger margins than the latex defaults
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in}
((* endblock commands *))

((* block bibliography *))
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Thesis}
((* endblock bibliography *))

% Disable input cells
((* block input_group *))
((* endblock input_group *))

((= This line selects the cell style. =))
((* set cell_style = 'style_bw_python.tplx' *))
```

Comment: Seems that it may be easiest and most transparent if I essentially made a copy of the the base template and made any additions and modifications there. Would you advise against this for any reason? Also - the base template says at the top 'This template does not define a docclass, the inheriting class must define this'. Does that mean that it isn't possible to define a docclass in a modified version of that template? Or just that that isn't what's done there?

Comment: If you simply copy the base template you miss not only the docclass (see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/nbconvert/templates/latex/article.tplx#L15)) but also the output style (e.g. [ipython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/nbconvert/templates/latex/style_ipython.tplx)) Of course you can copy everything you need into a new template, but I would inherit from the article class (like you did in your question) and try to extend the packages block using super.

Comment: @JGrif I've updated my answer with a possible template inheriting from `article.tplx`.

Comment: Thanks. The hypersetup call here doesn't do anything though; result is same when removed.

Comment: @JGrif you are totally right (sorry, I didn't tried the proposed version)! I've modified the `hypersetup` call to include _hidelinks_. This should disable link highlighting.